# ¿Puedo cancelar el sumbit de un formulario y evitar que llegue al controlador(servidor)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Me interesaria saber si puedo cancelar o evitar que el button submit me llegue al controlador. Como antes se ejecuta el evento .click de jquery, puede que des de allí pueda hacer algo al respeto y asi evitar que siga su ejecución.
Gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) es un evento que "técnicamente" pertenece al [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) de  javascript puro, no a JQuery como tal.

> Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

JQuery lo que hace es normalizar los eventos de acuerdo al estándard de [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/ecma-script-binding.html) garantizando que todo funcione como debería, por eso es que ese y otros eventos existen dentro del API.

> El sistema de eventos de jQuery's normaliza el objeto evento de acuerdo con los estándares de W3C. Está garantizado que el objeto sea pasado al manejador de eventos. La mayoría de las propiedades del evento original son copiados y normalizados en el nuevo objeto evento.

Si quieres cancelarlo deberías empezar sabiendo que todos los eventos no son [cancelables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable), submit afortunadamente si lo es. Para cancelarlo se usa [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) que internamente invoca al [event.prevenDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) nativo lo cual cancelará el evento.

```
 $("#myFormulario").on('submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();  
    // tu codigo aqui
 });
```

Debes saber también que los eventos se propagan, o sea que si tienes un elemento dentro de otro y se desencadena un evento dentro del elemento interior este se propagará al externo. Si los dos tienen eventos asociados se ejecutarán los dos. La forma de detener que esto ocurra es con [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) pero afortunadamente en html *poner un formulario html dentro de otro es ilegal*[<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555928/is-it-valid-to-have-a-html-form-inside-another-html-form) así que en este caso no tienes que preocuparte de que el evento se siga propagando.

Answer (score 3):

Con `jquery` puedes controlar el submit si usas

```
$("form").submit(function(e){

     e.preventDefault();

     //resto código   

 });
```

con el uso del `preventDefault` puede evitar la accion del submit y realizar alguna otra accion que necesites

Comment: Sólamente ejecutará el código que haya a continuación sin ejecutar el código del servidor? SIn llegar al controlador vaya.

Comment: exacto con el preventDefault anulas el submit del form, la accion al controller no se realiza