# Asignar atributo "data" a button con jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Estoy usando php, mysql y jquery. Tengo una funcion ajax que toma un valor `data` desde las propiedades de un button al hacer click sobre el:

```
<button data-user="12345" id="btnbusca" name="btnbusca" class="btn btn-primary input"></button>
```

Por ahora le tengo un valor asignado fijo pero quiero hacer que tome ese valor de un input text.

En conclusión: como hago para que el valor `data-user` lo obtenga desde un input text al hacer click sobre ese botón, ya que mi ajax necesita ese valor?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes leer directamente el valor usando `$(selector).val()` y lo envías directamente usando `$.ajax` sin necesidad de ponerselo al botón, no obstante si quieres manipular su `data-attribute` puedes usar el método [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
$(function() {
  'use strict';

  var boton = $('#btnbusca');
  var input = $('#source');
  var resultado = $('#resultado');

  boton.on('click', function() {
    boton.attr('data-user', input.val());
    resultado.text(boton.attr('data-user'));

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<input id="source" type="text" class="form-control">
<br>
<button data-user="12345" id="btnbusca" name="btnbusca" class="btn btn-primary input">
  Actualizar
</button>
<br>
<br>El valor almacenado es
<div id="resultado">
</div>
```

otra variante sería usando [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
$(function() {
  'use strict';

  var boton = $('#btnbusca');
  var resultado = $('#valor');
  var input = $('#source');

  boton.on('click', function() {
    var valor = input.val()
    boton.data('user', valor);

    resultado.text(boton.data('user'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<input id="source" type="text" class="form-control">
<br>
<button id="btnbusca" name="btnbusca" class="btn btn-primary input">
  Actualizar
</button>
<br>
<br>El valor almacenado es
<div id="valor"></div>
```

La diferencia entre los dos es que el método `.data` lee de los atributos `data-` del elemento

> Retorna el valor almacenado en la correspondiente llave para el primer elemento en la colección, como fue almacenado por el método `.data(name, value)` o por un atributo HTML5 `data-*`.

pero cuando escribes en ellos el atributo html no se actualiza, sin embargo cuando usas `.attr` lo que se cambia es el atributo como tal. Usualmente el método recomendado es `$.data` ya que es un api diseñado para almacenar datos arbitrarios

> Almacena datos arbitrarios en los elementos especificados o retorna el valor que fue almacenado.

Comment: gracias, me sirvio mucho. Pero por alguna razon funciona con doble click, no al click simple.

Comment: @daniel tienes el botón dentro de un formulario? prueba poniendole `type="button"` al boton.

Comment: si esta dentro del form y con type="button", no se que pasa

Comment: @daniel Eso es raro de verdad. Debe ser alguna otra parte de tu código que esta mal pues el evento `$(selector).on('click', handler)` lo único que hace es bindear el evento nativo [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/click) que es muy diferente al [doble click](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/dblclick). Lee http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/7147/2224 para que entiendas como funcionan los eventos de jQuery. No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió.

Comment: @daniel No te olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió

Answer (score 0):

Si es así entonces ya no necesitas el atributo en el `button`. Simplemente toma el valor desde el `input`

```js
$(function(){
  $("#btnbusca").click(function(){
    var valor = $("#texto").val();
    alert(valor);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="texto">Ingresa un valor:</label>
<input type="text" id="texto" />
<button id="btnbusca" name="btnbusca" class="btn btn-primary input" >Ejecutar</button>
```